# TYPE cause ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Tags: plsql

I have the following PL/SQL package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_JCSJ
AS      
TYPE  record_organ_cant  IS RECORD(CANT_CODE VARCHAR2(90),
        ORGAN_ID  VARCHAR2(90) ,
        CANT_NAME VARCHAR2(90),
        SUPP_TYPE VARCHAR2(20));

  --TYPE array_organ_cant IS TABLE of PKG_JCSJ.record_organ_cant;
  TYPE array_organ_cant IS TABLE of pub_organ_cant%ROWTYPE;

  function fn_transe_organ_cant return PKG_JCSJ.array_organ_cant PIPELINED;
 END PKG_JCSJ;

create or replace package body PKG_JCSJ is

function fn_transe_organ_cant return PKG_JCSJ.array_organ_cant PIPELINED
as
   cursor cursor_organ_cant is select * from pub_organ_cant ; 
   record_o_c pub_organ_cant%rowtype; 
   record_o_c2 pub_organ_cant%rowtype;        
   cant_code VARCHAR2(90); 

   TYPE ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR; 
   array_column_value ref_cursor;  
   sp_cant_code VARCHAR2(90); 

begin
   open cursor_organ_cant;
   loop
        fetch cursor_organ_cant into record_o_c;
        exit when cursor_organ_cant%notfound;
        cant_code := record_o_c.cant_code;
        if instr(cant_code, ',')>0 then
           open array_column_value for select * from  table(fn_split(cant_code));
           loop
                fetch array_column_value into sp_cant_code;
                exit when array_column_value%notfound;
                --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('---' || sp_cant_code);
                record_o_c2.CANT_CODE := sp_cant_code;
                record_o_c2.ORGAN_ID := record_o_c.ORGAN_ID;
                record_o_c2.CANT_NAME := record_o_c.CANT_NAME;
                record_o_c2.SUPP_TYPE := record_o_c.SUPP_TYPE;
                --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('++++++' || record_o_c2.CANT_CODE);

                PIPE ROW (record_o_c2);
           end loop;
           close array_column_value;
        else   
           PIPE ROW (record_o_c);
        end if;
   end loop;
   close cursor_organ_cant;
   return;
end fn_transe_organ_cant;
begin
   null;
end PKG_JCSJ;
```

Why is this statement failing?

```
TYPE array_organ_cant IS TABLE of PKG_JCSJ.record_organ_cant;
```

error info is `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error`. However, when I use the following statement, success!

```
TYPE array_organ_cant IS TABLE of pub_organ_cant%ROWTYPE;
```

`record_organ_cant` is same structure with TABLE `pub_organ_cant`, I have no idea why the former fails and the latter is successful, what's the difference?

then, package body as follow,

Comment: Can you post the full DDL for your table, for example the output from `select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'PUB_ORGAN_CANT', user) from dual;`.  Is it possible that the table is defined as `VARCHAR2(90 CHAR)`, but your package defaults to `VARCHAR2(90 BYTE)`?  Compare the table DDL with `select value from v$nls_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS';`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your package body you don't have to use `PKG_JCSJ.` because its declared within the pacakge and should be accessible to any of its function like

```
create or replace package body PKG_JCSJ is
function fn_transe_organ_cant return array_organ_cant PIPELINED
....
```

Next, when you declare again you don't need `PKG_JCSJ.` like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_JCSJ
AS      
  TYPE  record_organ_cant  IS RECORD(CANT_CODE VARCHAR2(90),
        ORGAN_ID  VARCHAR2(90) ,
        CANT_NAME VARCHAR2(90),
        SUPP_TYPE VARCHAR2(20));

  TYPE array_organ_cant IS TABLE of record_organ_cant;

  function fn_transe_organ_cant return array_organ_cant PIPELINED;
 END PKG_JCSJ;
```